# Triangles with specific round corners

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, data-visualisation, mathematics, corners

I'm working on a geometrical visualization project. The math stuff is done in [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing).
[image: geogebra]

Notice the smoothness of the lines. It all looks slick.

When I export this project to svg and open in Illustrator, I see this
[image]

All lines are rough and bumpy. There is no way I can make them smooth without artifacts.

I tried an alternative approach and drew rectangles with smooth corners. But the result is off too.

[image]

No matter what corner roundness is set, the resulting triangle looks nothing like the original from Geogebra.

Is this even possible in Illustrator? Are there other vector based tools, that can possibly draw shapes from math equations?

Comment: Maybe @joojaa's [joograph](https://bitbucket.org/joojaa/jooillustratorscripts/wiki/Documentation/jooGraphFunction) might help you here -- or any of his other Illustrator scripts.

Comment: @Vincent no that wont work in this case unfortunately. Yeah solving by grid is problematic in terms of getting good curve. Just join the curves and simplify.

Comment: Is SVG the only vector export option in that package?

Comment: @usr2564301 ist still generated that way

Comment: I don't know how useful this will be but Inkscape's Polygon tool can produce rounded triangles that are closer to these shapes. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/aImNkxF).

Comment: @joojaa Never hurts to try. Thanks for dropping in.

Comment: @BillyKerr Could you post a screenshot of Inkscape's Polygon tool options please?

Comment: Inkscape is free, it takes minutes to download and install. But anyway [here's the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/xbf3Ynh)

Comment: @Vincent ugh i tried it does not parametrisize easily but its pretty easy to do this by reorganizing code a bit